# Problem with AudioRecord class

Tags: android, audio-recording, android-audiorecord

I am recording audio using AudioRecord class.I want to record audio into a particular file in my asset folder or resource folder.I think there is no problem in recording.but while reading buffer it is showing some problem(it is throwing NullPointerException).Can anyone suggest what may be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not save file inside Asset folder. Assets folder is read only instead of it you will have to save it in the internal or external storage of your device

Below there is a core to record the media file.

```
package com.example.media.record;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.media.MediaPlayer;
    import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;
    import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener;
    import android.media.MediaRecorder;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Environment;
    import android.os.Handler;
    import android.os.Handler.Callback;
    import android.os.Message;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.ProgressBar;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class MediaRecorderActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
        Button btnPlay;
        Button btnRecord;
        ProgressBar progress;
        MediaPlayer mPlayer;
        MediaRecorder mRecorder;
        String mFileName;
        boolean mStartRecording = true;
        boolean mStartPlaying = true;
        Thread mThreadProgress;
        int duration = 1;
        private void onRecord(boolean start) {
            if(start) {
                startRecording();
            }else {
                stopRecording();
            }
        }

        private void onPlay(boolean start) {
            if(start) {
                startPlaying();
            }else {
                stopPlaying();
            }
        }

        private void startRecording() {
            mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
            mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
            mRecorder.setOutputFile(mFileName);
            mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
            mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
            mRecorder.setOnErrorListener(errorListenerForRecorder);

            try {
                mRecorder.prepare();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                mRecorder.start();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error :: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }


        private void stopRecording() {
            if(mRecorder != null) {
                mRecorder.stop();
                mRecorder.release();
                mRecorder = null;
            }
        }

        private void startPlaying() {
            mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            try {
                mPlayer.setDataSource(mFileName);
                mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(completionListener);
                mPlayer.setOnErrorListener(errorListenerForPlayer);
                mPlayer.prepare();
                mPlayer.start();
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        private void stopPlaying() {
            if(mPlayer != null) {
                mPlayer.stop();
                mPlayer.release();
                mPlayer = null;
            }
        }

        OnCompletionListener completionListener = new OnCompletionListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                btnRecord.setEnabled(true);
                btnPlay.setText("Start playing");
                mStartPlaying = !mStartPlaying;
            }
        };

        OnErrorListener errorListenerForPlayer = new OnErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error during playing file", 3000).show();
                return false;
            }
        };

        android.media.MediaRecorder.OnErrorListener errorListenerForRecorder = new android.media.MediaRecorder.OnErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onError(MediaRecorder mr, int what, int extra) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error during recoding file", 3000).show();

            }
        };
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            btnPlay = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);
            btnRecord = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnRecord);
            progress = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressRecorder);
            mFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
            mFileName += "/audiorecordtest.3gp";
            File file = new File(mFileName);
            if(!file.exists()) btnPlay.setEnabled(false); 
            btnPlay.setOnClickListener(this);
            btnRecord.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            if(mRecorder != null) {
                mRecorder.stop();
            }
            if(mPlayer != null) {
                mPlayer.pause();
            }
        }


        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            if(mRecorder != null) {
                mRecorder.start();
            }
            if(mPlayer != null) {
                mPlayer.start();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onStop() {
            super.onStop();
            if(mRecorder != null) {
                mRecorder.stop();
            }
            if(mPlayer != null) {
                mPlayer.stop();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            if(mRecorder != null) {
                mRecorder.release();
                mRecorder = null;
            }
            if(mPlayer != null) {
                mPlayer.release();
                mPlayer = null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(v == btnPlay) {

                onPlay(mStartPlaying);
                if(mStartPlaying) {
                    duration = mPlayer.getDuration();
                    mThreadProgress = new ThreadProgress();
                    mThreadProgress.start();
                    ((Button)v).setText("Stop Playing");
                    btnRecord.setEnabled(false);

                }
                else {
                    ((Button)v).setText("Start Playing");
                    btnRecord.setEnabled(true);
                    if(mThreadProgress != null && !mThreadProgress.isAlive()) mThreadProgress.stop();

                    //  t.interrupt();
                }
                mStartPlaying = !mStartPlaying;

            } else if(v == btnRecord) {
                onRecord(mStartRecording);
                if(mStartRecording) {
                    mThreadProgress = new ThreadProgress();
                    mThreadProgress.start();
                    ((Button)v).setText("Stop Recording");
                    btnPlay.setEnabled(false);
                    //  t.start();
                }
                else {
                    ((Button)v).setText("Start Recording");
                    btnPlay.setEnabled(true);
                    //  t.interrupt();
                    if(mThreadProgress != null && !mThreadProgress.isAlive()) mThreadProgress.stop();
                }
                mStartRecording = !mStartRecording;
            }
        }


        Handler handler = new Handler(new Callback() {

            @Override
            public boolean handleMessage(final Message msg) {
                if(msg.what == 0) {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            progress.setProgress(msg.arg1);
                        }
                    });

                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        public class ThreadProgress extends Thread implements Runnable {

            public int i = 0;
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while((!this.isInterrupted() && mPlayer != null && mPlayer.isPlaying()) || (!this.isInterrupted() && mRecorder != null)) {
                    try {
                        if(duration == 1) i+=1;
                        else i += 100000 /duration;
                        Message message = new Message();
                        message.what = 0;
                        message.arg1 = i;
                        handler.sendMessage(message);
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }       
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

This is the example you can record audio as well as play audio

```
You can store recorded file in following places
1) File directory of your app
2) External directory(SD card)
3) Network
```

Comment: Thanks.But Can you tell me how to set output file.I want to store recorded file inside assets folder like assets/record/a.wav.How can i do this.i m not doing like this:      recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);  
        recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
        recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB); recordPath="file:///android_asset/record/a.wav"; recorder.setOutputFile(recordPath); recorder.prepare(); recorder.start();

Comment: I think Asset folder is read only you can not store inside assets by code

Comment: ok.Allright.But any idea how to store in raw folder inside resource folder then?

Comment: you can't even create a file inside row folder programetically

Comment: no.Let me make clear i am putting a folder(created explicitly not programmatically) inside "res" folder then how can i use it in storing my recorded voice?

Comment: that i am saying that this folder can use to store files explicitly not programmatically. After that we can read files from that folder but can't write in that.

Comment: Thanks again buddy.But then how can i store my recorded voice and play it.Please suggest.There must be someway.

Comment: i have edited my answer check it.Now if you don't have any issue then you can accept answer.

Comment: I will definitely for sure.External directory(SD card) and Network i got it.But what do you mean by File directory? Is it any directory in my computer or workspace?

Comment: thanks so much buddy.Just one more thing how can i give path to phone memory in setOutputFile() in MediaRecorder and also how can i read to play that recorded voice.I searched many forums but didnot get any idea.

Comment: you can use just file name so default it will use internal directory of device

Comment: Is there anyway to do like if phone memory is full it will go to SDCARD ?

Comment: AndroidMirza there is long discussion here between us here so you have any query other than this then you have to ask a new question but before that you have to search it